# PHP not loading sqlsrv extension

Tags: php, iis, sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm having trouble getting PHP to use Microsoft's `sqlsrv` extension on 64bit Windows server 2012 R2 running IIS and PHP 7.1.7.  When I run `phpinfo()` I don't see that the extension has been loaded.  I'm assuming I should be looking for `sqlsrv` as the the extension name.  There is also no error in the PHP error log of any sort of failure loading the extension.

I downloaded version 4.3 of the Microsoft's drivers which state they are compatible with PHP 7.1.  I have copied the dll files into the `PHP\v7.1\ext` directory.  I added the following lines to the php.ini file.

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
```

I have verified that my php.ini file is being read by intentionally misspelling one of the dll names and seeing a corresponding error in the php log.

SQL Server Native Client 10 and 11 is installed.

I have recycled the application pool, restarted the W3SVC service, and restarted the server.

I'm hoping someone here can offer some other things to try.

Comment: For some reason the error log was not showing any errors when trying to load the extension.  I changed the log file name and found the following error.    [29-Nov-2017 16:22:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.1\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Add your new info directly in your question instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem, which I haven't solved yet is my php error log isn't showing extension loading issues unless I change the log file name.  After changing the log file name I received the following error:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.1\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.

As it turns out I needed to use the driver specific to PHP 7.1.  I'm not sure why, by my original download didn't include the 7.1 drivers.  Perhaps I mistakenly downloaded the sqlsrv 4.0 driver my first time around.  I went and downloaded the sqlsrv 4.3 driver here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55642

I added the following to my php.ini

extension=php_sqlsrv_71_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts_x64.dl

sqlsrv extenion is loaded now.  I hope this helps someone else.